# ANDROID - display image and text from separate web service calls

Tags: android, json

I need your advice or ideas regarding my problem. The app I'm working on needs to display an image and text from two separate web services. The first web service (image) returns a base64 encoded string and the last web service(text) returns a plain json response.

Some samples I found on the web is that they only use one service to display the record with the the string url of image something like this:

```
[{"id":"1","version_name":"Alpha","description":"","version_code":"1.0","api_level":"1","image":"http:\/\/www.test.com/img/cupcake.jpg"}]
```

But in my case, the client has given me two separate calls to view the data (details) and image:

```
[{"id":"1","version_name":"Alpha","description":"","version_code":"1.0","api_level":"1"}]
```

for image Base64 String result (SAMPLE):

```
 "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
```

To display this in a listview, how would I display them at the same time? How would you create a workaround for this? 
I would truly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: what are you using for making the network calls asynctask or something else?

Comment: `I found on the web is that they only use one service to display the record with the the string url of image` but in most webservices image url in mentioned and image is retrieved using Lazy loading. you can do in same way and retrive and save string as image

Comment: Base64 is heavy where as simple text is not. It requires more time to process the heavy string. So your loader (ProcessDialog) should work according to Base64 and not text. Once you get Base64, compress it and then set it to ImageView along with that text. Note: Waiting time can be huge!

Comment: @PramodYadav I'm using AsyncTask

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K yes but is there a way to display the text and encoded string at the same time?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes: you can do it by calling image webservice during parsing of text json string

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK can you give me some sample codes to do that? Or an Asynctask code to do that? I'm still confused. thanks